# Need to further optimize code

Tags: java

Following is the code which I need to optimize:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum=0;           //stores the result
```

Creating 4 lists, A B C to save the input values respectively, D to get the final list of results and S to store the sums.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listC = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listD = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listS = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Getting the total number of test cases

```
    int T = sc.nextInt();
```

The first line of each testcase contains 3 integers: p, q and r. These denote the lengths of A,B and C respectively.
The second line contains p integers, which are the elements of A. The third line contains q integers, which are the elements of B. The fourth line contains r integers, which are the elements of C.

```
    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        int p = sc.nextInt();
        int q = sc.nextInt();
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        for(int j=0; j<p; j++){
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            listA.add(x);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<q; j++){
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            listB.add(x);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<r; j++){
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            listC.add(x);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < listA.size(); k++){
            int a = listA.get(k);
            for(int j=0; j<listB.size(); j++){
                int b = listB.get(j);
                for(int l=0; l<listC.size(); l++){
                    int c=listC.get(l);
                    //System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b+" c: "+c);
                    int d = (a+b)*(b+c);
                    listD.add(d);
                }
            }

        }
        for(int y=0; y<listD.size(); y++){
            sum += listD.get(y);
        }
        sum = sum%1000000007;
        System.out.println(listD);
        listS.add(sum);

    }
    String formattedString = listS.toString()
            .replace(",", "\n")  //remove the commas
            .replace("[", "")  //remove the right bracket
            .replace("]", "")  //remove the left bracket
            .replace(" ", "")
            .trim(); 
    System.out.println(formattedString);
    sc.close();
```

Is there any way to reduce all the nested loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you need to calculate the value of `sum` in the above code which is basically the sum of all possible permutations of `(a+b)*(b+c)`. I formulated this into a simple sigma equation and simplified it as follows:

[image]

From the last equation above if you consider the sum of each list to be X, Y and Z respectively, the above equation boils down to:

```
sum=rXY+qXZ+pr*(sum of squares of each element in listB)+p*YZ
```

This is of the order of `O(q^2)` in worst case as compared to `O(pqr)` in your code.

Comment: This works perfectly! but what if before doing (a+b)*(b+c) of all possible permutations, I also wish to check if a<=b and b>=c?

Comment: So basically based on the outcome of that condition you want to multiply?

Comment: yup! you got it.

Comment: that makes it very simple then. Just sort all the lists. Iterate over `a` until you find a value less than `b`. When you do iterate over `c` to find the _values_ which match `b>=c`

Comment: Oh yes. that should work! I'll try this now. thank you!